# Print results from two tables with no common columns ordered by date

Tags: mysql

This is what I last tried.

```
(
SELECT  
`offers`.`id` AS `offer`, `offers`.`date` 
from `offers`
WHERE `offers`.`expired`='0'
ORDER BY `offers`.`date` DESC LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT  
`vlog`.`video`,
`vlog`.`updated`
from `vlog`
ORDER BY `vlog`.`date` DESC LIMIT 10
)
```

For simplicity's sake, I have only two columns. I need to sort them by the date (not in the same results the code above provides) and show which is an offer and which is a video. Is this possible with no columns that link the tables.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `video.video` is an ID, since it lines up with the `id` column in the top query. You can select a literal string in both queries to indicate which query it came from:

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5fae/2)

```
SELECT
    'offer' AS type,
    id,
    date
FROM
    offers
WHERE
    expired = 0
UNION
SELECT
    'video' AS type,
    video AS id,
    updated AS date
FROM
    vlog
ORDER BY
    date
```

Comment: Thank you, the "type" is the perfect way to know which is which. however, the union is still printing all of the videos and then all of the offers.

Comment: Wait, that worked perfect!! Thank you all together. I'm going to accept your answer. Please msg me if there is  something else I am suppose to do. Thanks Again.